# What does .contiguous() do in PyTorch?

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, contiguous

What does `x.contiguous()` do for a tensor `x`?

Comment: cross-posted: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-do-we-need-to-call-contiguous-in-Pytorch

Comment: An answer from the forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/contigious-vs-non-contigious-tensor/30107/2

Comment: when is a case that we **do** need to call `contiguous`?

Answer (score 356, accepted):

There are a few operations on Tensors in PyTorch that do not change the contents of a tensor, but change the way the data is organized. These operations include:

> `narrow()`, `view()`, `expand()` and `transpose()`

*For example:* when you call `transpose()`, PyTorch doesn't generate a new tensor with a new layout, it just modifies meta information in the Tensor object so that the offset and stride describe the desired new shape. In this example, the transposed tensor and original tensor share the same memory:

```py
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = torch.transpose(x, 0, 1)
x[0, 0] = 42
print(y[0,0])
# prints 42
```

This is where the concept of *contiguous* comes in. In the example above, `x` is contiguous but `y` is not because its memory layout is different to that of a tensor of same shape made from scratch. Note that the word *"contiguous"* is a bit misleading because it's not that the content of the tensor is spread out around disconnected blocks of memory. Here bytes are still allocated in one block of memory but the order of the elements is different!

When you call `contiguous()`, it actually makes a copy of the tensor such that the order of its elements in memory is the same as if it had been created from scratch with the same data.

Normally you don't need to worry about this. You're generally safe to assume everything will work, and wait until you get a `RuntimeError: input is not contiguous` where PyTorch expects a contiguous tensor to add a call to `contiguous()`.

Comment: I just came across this again. Your explanation is very good! I just wonder: If the blocks in memory are not widely spread, what is the problem with a memory layout that is *"different than a tensor of same shape made from scratch"*? Why is being contiguous only requirement for some operations?

Comment: I can't definitively answer this but my guess is that some of the PyTorch code uses high performance vectorized implementation of the operations implemented in C++ and this code cannot use arbitrary offset/strides specified in Tensor's meta information. This is just a guess though.

Comment: Why couldn't the callee simply call `contiguous()` by itself?

Comment: quite possibly, because you don't want it in a contiguous way, and it is always nice to have control over what you do.

Comment: Another popular tensor operation is `permute`, which also may return non-"contiguous" tensor.

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. Pytorch uses an incorrect & misleading term for meaning only that the memory of the tensor is NOT of what is advertised by print statements or querying its meta-data?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be appropriate if I understood `contiguous` to being analogous to deep copying?

Comment: Attention, use contiguous wil slow down the operation on tensors as it will require to allocate new space on ram:
```In [132]: %timeit x.T.contiguous()                                                                                                     
4.73 µs ± 36.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [133]: %timeit x.T                                                                                                                  
1.88 µs ± 46.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: If `contiguous` creates a copy, does that prevent autodiff from computing gradients through the original tensor?

Comment: `x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = torch.transpose(x, 0, 1).contiguous()`
by adding the `contiguous()` to the transpose of `x` gives a new tensor in  the memory I think because when changing `x` values doesn't any more effects the `y` values (with this way it's act like copy).
but doing it as follow `y = x.contiguous().transpose(0, 1)` the `contiguous` doesn't work anymore like copy

Comment: when is a case that we **do** need to call `contiguous`?

Comment: @CharlieParker I also wonder about cases where `contiguous` is needed. I posted this as a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840389/what-functions-or-modules-require-contiguous-input/).

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation. Btw, the result of `view` is `contiguous`. In contrast, the result of `permute` or `transpose` is **not** contiguous. For example, even if we call `.view` many times with different shapes, it works fine without using the `contiguous()` method. But if we permute or transpose first, and then try to `view`, then an error occurs, because `view` only works on the "contiguous" tensor(we need to use `.contiguous()` before `view` to create a contiguous tensor, by creating a new, rearranged underlying storage).

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I understood the goal of using `contiguous()` but what I didn't understand was your sample code. I didn't get how the sample code shows the contiguous concept in PyTorch Tensors. I would appreciate it if you explain more about it.

Answer (score 73):

A one-dimensional array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is contiguous if its items are laid out in memory next to each other just like below:

[image: contiguous memory allocation]

It is not contiguous if the region of memory where it is stored looks like this:

[image: non contiguous allocation]

For 2-dimensional arrays or more, items must also be next to each other, but the order follow different conventions.
Let's consider the 2D-array below:

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]])
```

[image: two dimensional array]

The memory allocation is **C contiguous** if the rows are stored next to each other like this:

[image: two dimensional memory]

This is what PyTorch considers contiguous.

```
>>> t.is_contiguous()
True
```

PyTorch's Tensor class method [`stride()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.stride.html) gives the number of bytes to skip to get the next element in each dimension

```
>>> t.stride()
(4, 1)
```

We need to skip 4 bytes to go to the next line, but only one byte to go to the next element in the same line.

As said in other answers, some Pytorch operations do not change the memory allocation, only metadata.

For instance the transpose method.
Let's transpose the tensor:

[image: two dimensional array]

The memory allocation didn't change:

[image: two dimensional memory non contiguous]

But the stride did:

```
>>> t.T.stride()
(1, 4)
```

We need to skip 1 byte to go to the next line and 4 bytes to go to the next element in the same line. The tensor is not C contiguous anymore (it is in fact *Fortran contiguous*: each column is stored next to each other)

```
>>> t.T.is_contiguous()
False
```

[`contiguous()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.contiguous.html) will rearrange the memory allocation so that the tensor is C contiguous:

[image: two dimensional memory contiguous]

```
>>> t.T.contiguous().stride()
(3, 1)
```

Some operations, such as [`reshape()` and `view()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69637289/4815835), will have a different impact on the contiguity of the underlying data.

Answer (score 47):

From the [pytorch documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html):

> `contiguous() → Tensor`
> Returns a contiguous tensor containing the same data as self
> tensor. If self tensor is contiguous, this function returns the self
> tensor.

Where `contiguous` here means not only contiguous in memory, but also in the same order in memory as the indices order: for example doing a transposition doesn't change the data in memory, it simply changes the map from indices to memory pointers, if you then apply `contiguous()` it will change the data in memory so that the map from indices to memory location is the canonical one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you tell me why/when I need the data to be contiguous? Is it just performance, or some other reason? Does PyTorch require contiguous data for some operations?
Why does targets need to be contiguous and inputs not?

Comment: So apparently pytorch requires the targets in the loss to be continguous in memory, but the inputs of neuralnet don't need to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Great thank you! I think this makes sense to me, I've noticed that contiguous() is also applied to the output data (which was of course formerly the input) in the forward function, so both outputs and targets are contiguous when computing the loss.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: when is the data not in contiguous blocks? Why would it matter how its stored?

Comment: @CharlieParker I have no idea.

Comment: If contiguous creates a copy, does that prevent autodiff from computing gradients through the original tensor?

Comment: when is a case that we **do** need to call `contiguous`?

Comment: @CharlieParker if you don't use it and you need it, torch will give you an error that you need. Some tensor operations require contiguous tensors but not all.

Comment: @patapouf_ai great to know it will tell me on its own if it needs it. But out of curiosity, do you need why it's needed?

Comment: @CharlieParker some torch operations only work when the index order of the tensor matches the order in memory, the coding of the operation assumes consistency between both.

Answer (score 23):

tensor.contiguous() will create a copy of the tensor, and the element in the copy will be stored in the memory in a contiguous way.
The contiguous() function is usually required when we first transpose() a tensor and then reshape (view) it. First, let's create a contiguous tensor:

```
aaa = torch.Tensor( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] )
print(aaa.stride())
print(aaa.is_contiguous())
#(3,1)
#True
```

The stride() return (3,1) means that: when moving along the first dimension by each step (row by row), we need to move 3 steps in the memory. When moving along the second dimension (column by column), we need to move 1 step in the memory. This indicates that the elements in the tensor are stored contiguously.

Now we try apply come functions to the tensor:

```
bbb = aaa.transpose(0,1)
print(bbb.stride())
print(bbb.is_contiguous())

#(1, 3)
#False


ccc = aaa.narrow(1,1,2)   ## equivalent to matrix slicing aaa[:,1:3]
print(ccc.stride())
print(ccc.is_contiguous())

#(3, 1)
#False


ddd = aaa.repeat(2,1)   # The first dimension repeat once, the second dimension repeat twice
print(ddd.stride())
print(ddd.is_contiguous())

#(3, 1)
#True


## expand is different from repeat.
## if a tensor has a shape [d1,d2,1], it can only be expanded using "expand(d1,d2,d3)", which
## means the singleton dimension is repeated d3 times
eee = aaa.unsqueeze(2).expand(2,3,3)
print(eee.stride())
print(eee.is_contiguous())

#(3, 1, 0)
#False


fff = aaa.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1,1,8).view(2,-1,2)
print(fff.stride())
print(fff.is_contiguous())

#(24, 2, 1)
#True
```

Ok, we can find that **transpose(), narrow() and tensor slicing, and expand()** will make the generated tensor not contiguous. Interestingly, repeat() and view() does not make it discontiguous. So now the question is: **what happens if I use a discontiguous tensor?**

The answer is it the view() function cannot be applied to a discontiguous tensor. This is probably because view() requires that the tensor to be contiguously stored so that it can do fast reshape in memory. e.g:

```
bbb.view(-1,3)
```

we will get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-eec5319b0ac5> in <module>()
----> 1 bbb.view(-1,3)

RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Call .contiguous() before .view(). at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:203
```

To solve this, simply add contiguous() to a discontiguous tensor, to create contiguous copy and then apply view()

```
bbb.contiguous().view(-1,3)
#tensor([[1., 4., 2.],
        [5., 3., 6.]])
```

Comment: If contiguous creates a copy, does that prevent autodiff from computing gradients through the original tensor?

Answer (score 10):

As in the previous answer contigous() allocates **contigous memory chunks**, it'll be helpful when we're **passing tensor to c or c++ backend code** where tensors are **passed as pointers**

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answers were so great, and I tried to dupe the `transpose()` function effect. I created the two functions that can check the `samestorage()` and the `contiguous`.

```py
def samestorage(x,y):
    if x.storage().data_ptr()==y.storage().data_ptr():
        print("same storage")
    else:
        print("different storage")
def contiguous(y):
    if True==y.is_contiguous():
        print("contiguous")
    else:
        print("non contiguous")
```

I checked and got this result as a table:

[image: functions]

You can review the checker code down below, but let's give one example when the tensor is *non contiguous*. We cannot simply call `view()` on that tensor, we would need to `reshape()` it or we could also call `.contiguous().view()`.

```
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.transpose(0, 1)
y.view(6) # RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
  
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.transpose(0, 1)
y.reshape(6)

x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.transpose(0, 1)
y.contiguous().view(6)
```

Further to note there are methods that create *contiguous* and *non contiguous* tensors in the end. There are methods that can operate on a *same storage*, and some methods as `flip()` that will create a *new storage* (read: clone the tensor) before returning.

The checker code:

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.transpose(0, 1) # flips two axes
print("\ntranspose")
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\nnarrow")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.narrow(0, 1, 2) #dim, start, len  
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\npermute")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.permute(1, 0) # sets the axis order
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\nview")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y=x.view(2,3)
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\nreshape")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.reshape(6,1)
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\nflip")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.flip(0)
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)

print("\nexpand")
x = torch.randn(3,2)
y = x.expand(2,-1,-1)
print(x)
print(y)
contiguous(y)
samestorage(x,y)
```

Comment: return from torch.narrow is not always contiguous. It depends on dimension

```In [145]: x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])                                                                          

In [146]: torch.narrow(x, 1, 1, 2).is_contiguous()                                                                                     
Out[146]: False```

Comment: @Saibō, feel free to update with this tip.

Answer (score 3):

> **A tensor whose values are laid out in the storage starting from the rightmost dimension onward (that is, moving along rows for a 2D tensor) is defined as `contiguous`.** Contiguous tensors are convenient because we can visit them efficiently in order without jumping around in the storage (improving data locality improves performance because of the way memory access works on modern CPUs). This advantage of course depends on the way algorithms visit.
>
> Some tensor operations in PyTorch only work on contiguous tensors, such as `view`, [...]. In that case, PyTorch will throw an informative exception and require us to call contiguous explicitly. It’s worth noting that calling `contiguous` will do nothing (and will not hurt performance) if the tensor is already contiguous.

- [Deep Learning with PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf)

Note this is a more specific meaning than the general use of the word "contiguous" in computer science (i.e. contiguous *and ordered*).

e.g given a tensor:

```py
[[1, 2]
 [3, 4]]
```

| Storage in memory | PyTorch `contiguous`? | Generally "contiguous" in memory-space? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1 2 3 4 0 0 0` | ✅ | ✅ |
| `1 3 2 4 0 0 0` | ❌ | ✅ |
| `1 0 2 0 3 0 4` | ❌ | ❌ |

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this a more summarized answer:

> Contiguous is the term used to indicate that the memory layout of a tensor does not align with its advertised meta-data or shape information.

In my opinion the word contiguous is a confusing/misleading term since in normal contexts it means when memory is not spread around in disconnected blocks (i.e. its "contiguous/connected/continuous").

Some operations might need this contiguous property for some reason (most likely efficiency in gpu etc).

Note that `.view` is another operation that might cause this issue. Look at the following code I fixed by simply calling contiguous (instead of the typical transpose issue causing it here is an example that is cause when an RNN is not happy with its input):

```
        # normal lstm([loss, grad_prep, train_err]) = lstm(xn)
        n_learner_params = xn_lstm.size(1)
        (lstmh, lstmc) = hs[0] # previous hx from first (standard) lstm i.e. lstm_hx = (lstmh, lstmc) = hs[0]
        if lstmh.size(1) != xn_lstm.size(1): # only true when prev lstm_hx is equal to decoder/controllers hx
            # make sure that h, c from decoder/controller has the right size to go into the meta-optimizer
            expand_size = torch.Size([1,n_learner_params,self.lstm.hidden_size])
            lstmh, lstmc = lstmh.squeeze(0).expand(expand_size).contiguous(), lstmc.squeeze(0).expand(expand_size).contiguous()
        lstm_out, (lstmh, lstmc) = self.lstm(input=xn_lstm, hx=(lstmh, lstmc))
```

Error I used to get:

```
RuntimeError: rnn: hx is not contiguous
```

---

Sources/Resource:

- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/contigious-vs-non-contigious-tensor/30107/7
- [PyTorch - contiguous()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915810/pytorch-contiguous)