# In Pytorch there is a error to load new image in tensor and show it as pucture

Tags: file-upload, pytorch, dataset, tensor

I have added some new color images in the dataset, but show method display it wrong:
`test_dataset.show_data(2, show_annotation=False)`
[example with new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmvur.png).
But old pictures are displayed correctly:`test_dataset.show_data(12, show_annotation=False)` [correctly displayed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBy0C.png)

I've searched but haven't been able to find the error myself yet. **Help me please, what is the error?** Here is code for three methods in dataset class:

```
    # Getter
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # load image and return it as tensor
        fn = os.path.join(self.images_path, self.im.file_name[index])
        orig_width  = self.width
        orig_height = self.height 
        if os.path.exists(fn):
            image_ins = Image.open(fn)
            """
            orig_width  = image_ins.size[0]
            orig_height = image_ins.size[1]
            image_ins = image_ins.resize((self.width, self.height))
            """
            image_ins = image_ins.convert('RGB') #convert image to RGB channel
            image_tensor = self.transform(image_ins)
        else:
            image_tensor = torch.Tensor([0.0])
            
        # Prepare target dict for torchvision model
        boxes = self.ann[["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"]] \
                         [self.ann.id==self.im.id[index]].values.tolist()
        """
        # Resize boxes coords
        if (orig_width != self.width) or (orig_height != self.height):
            x_ratio = self.width  / orig_width
            y_ratio = self.height / orig_height
            boxes = [[b[0]*x_ratio, b[1]*y_ratio, b[2]*x_ratio, b[3]*y_ratio] for b in boxes]
        """        
        len_boxes = len(boxes)
        # Handle empty bounding boxes
        if len_boxes == 0:
            boxes = torch.zeros((0, 4), dtype=torch.float32)
        else:
            boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32) 
        labels = torch.ones((len_boxes,), dtype=torch.int64)
        image_id = torch.tensor([index])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((len_boxes,), dtype=torch.int64)
        
        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["image_id"] =  image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd
        return image_tensor, target
        
    # Show image with annotations
    def show_data(self, index, width=None, height=None, show_annotation=True,\
                  RoI_model=None, RoI_try_num=None):
        """
        Args:
            index: index of the image
            width, height: displaing size, we take default values from dataset
            show_annotaion: True - add annotation boxes
            RoI_model, RoI_try_num - optional, add detected RoI with saved model and try_num
        """
        if width==None or height==None:
            width = self.im.width[index]
            height = self.im.height[index]
        
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        # reshape when increase
        #ax.imshow(self[index][0].detach().numpy().reshape()) #cmap='gray'
        ax.imshow(self[index][0].detach().numpy().reshape(height, width, 3))
        ax.set_title('file = '+ str(self.im.file_name[index]))
        
        if show_annotation:
            # Select all annotation boxes for this image
            boxes_df = self.ann[self.ann.id==self.im.id[index]]
            if boxes_df.shape[0] > 0:
                x_scale = width  / self.im.width[index]
                y_scale = height / self.im.height[index]
                ann_boxes =  [Rectangle((row[0]*x_scale, row[1]*y_scale),\
                                       (row[2]-row[0])*x_scale, (row[3]-row[1])*y_scale) \
                             for row in boxes_df[["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"]].to_numpy()]

                # Create patch collection
                pc = PatchCollection(ann_boxes, facecolor="none", edgecolor="blue", alpha=0.5)
                # Add collection to axes
                ax.add_collection(pc)
                blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Annotations from a trainer')
                red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label="Detected RoI's")
                ax.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch], fontsize="small")
                
        # Model and try_num for RoI is selected to add RoI boxes
        if type(RoI_model)==str and type(RoI_try_num)==int:
            boxes_df = self.RoI[(self.RoI.im_id==self.im.iloc[index, 0]) \
                               &(self.RoI.model==RoI_model) \
                               &(self.RoI.try_num==RoI_try_num)]
            if boxes_df.shape[0] > 0:
                x_scale = width  / self.im.width[index]
                y_scale = height / self.im.height[index]
                RoI_boxes =  [Rectangle((row[0]*x_scale, row[1]*y_scale),\
                                       (row[2]-row[0])*x_scale, (row[3]-row[1])*y_scale) \
                              for row in boxes_df[["x", "y", "dx", "dy"]].to_numpy()]

                # Create patch collection
                pc = PatchCollection(RoI_boxes, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", alpha=0.5)
                # Add collection to axes
                ax.add_collection(pc)

    # Add images to dataset from directory
    def add_images(self, directory="C:\\temp\\datasets\\mediag\\images\\expert_images\\"):
        """
        Args:
            directory: the directory with images to add in this dataset
        """
        
        # Select all images from directory to list
        prep_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) \
                                      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f)) \
                                     and (f[-4:]==".jpg" or f[-5:]==".jpeg") \
                                     and os.stat(os.path.join(directory, f)).st_size>1000]
        # Copy file into dataset folder
        for f in prep_files:
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(directory, f), os.path.join(self.images_path, f))
        # fill parameters for new images
        prep_im = pd.DataFrame(columns = self.im.columns)
        prep_im["file_name"] = prep_files
        prep_im["cell_type"] = prep_im["file_name"].str.split("_", n=1, expand=True)[0]
        full_file_name = [os.path.join(self.images_path, f_n)
                          for f_n in prep_im["file_name"]]
        prep_im_size = pd.DataFrame([image_size(f_f_n) for f_f_n in full_file_name])
        prep_im["width"]  = prep_im_size[0]
        prep_im["height"] = prep_im_size[1]
        max_id = self.im.id.max()
        prep_im["id"] = max_id + prep_im.index + 1
        
        ## drop dublicates from dataset (detected by file_name)
        dubl_files = self.im[self.im["file_name"].isin(prep_files)].index
        self.im.drop(dubl_files, axis=0, inplace=True)
        
        self.im = pd.concat([prep_im, self.im])
        self.im.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        
        # import expert annotations (TBD)
        
        # update dataset parameters
        self.len = self.im.shape[0]
```

I have commented resize code in getter method, and try to skip convert to RGB command `image_ins = image_ins.convert('RGB')`.

Comment: It is likely a problem with permuted dimensions, make sure the channel dimension is on the right dimension index.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ivan. From your comment I found a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541192/display-pytorch-tensor-as-image-using-matplotlib