# pytorch view tensor and reduce one dimension

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

So I have a 4d tensor with shape `[4,1,128,678]` and I would like to view/reshape it as `[4,678,128]`.

I have to do this for multiple tensors where the last shape value 678 is not always know and could be different, so `[4,1,128,575]`should also go to `[4,575,128]`

Any idea on what is the optimal operation to transform the tensor? view/reshape? and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use (less to write and IMO cleaner):

```
# x.shape == (4, 1, 128, 678)
x.squeeze().permute(0, 2, 1)
```

If you were to use `view` you would lose dimension information (but maybe that is what you want), in this case it would be:

```
x.squeeze().view(4, -1, 128)
```

`permute` reorders tensors, while shape only gives a different view **without** restructuring underlying memory. You can see the difference between those two operations [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143206/difference-between-tensor-permute-and-tensor-view-in-pytorch).

Answer (score -1):

Use einops instead, it can do all operations in one turn and verify known dimensions:

```
from einops import reshape
y = rearrange(x, 'x 1 y z -> x z y', x=4, y=128)
```