# RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous

Tags: pytorch, tensor, multiplication

I got it when I was running:

```py
def case3():
    a = torch.randn(2,2)
    torch.kron(a,a.T)
```

but it works for torch.kron(a,a)
And then I try:

```py
def case4():
    a = torch.randn(1,4)
    torch.kron(a,a.T)
```

It works! So I am confusing why torch.kron would not work on tensor of size 2x2? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by myself!

The reason lies in that `.T` actually only reshape and shows the tensor instead of changing the actual tensor in memory.
so by modifying it as this, it solves the problem

```py
def case4():
    a = torch.randn(2,2)
    b = a.T.contiguous()
    print(torch.kron(a,b))
    print(torch.kron(a,a))
```

`.contiguous` makes a copy of tensor

referring to [What does .contiguous() do in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915810/what-does-contiguous-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: But it still doubts that why torch.mul(a,a.T) can work but torch.kron didn't. And kron can actually work for 2D matrix of any shape, why it didn't work?