# Does TORCH.TRANSPOSE change memory layout or just the view?

Tags: pytorch

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.T says Tensor.T

> Returns a view of this tensor with its dimensions reversed.

I wonder if [TORCH.TRANSPOSE](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) is the same.

---

Update

Found this post helpful
[What does .contiguous() do in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915810/what-does-contiguous-do-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually mentioned in the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html):

> If input is a strided tensor then the resulting out tensor shares its
> underlying storage with the input tensor, so changing the content of
> one would change the content of the other.
>
> If input is a sparse tensor then the resulting out tensor does not
> share the underlying storage with the input tensor.

So, eseentially if the input is a strided tensor, the output would be a view; for a sparse tensor, it's copied.